# Using DateObjects to serve as delimiters to make sublists of a string list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of strings. Interspersed in the list are long forms of dates, followed by data pertaining to that date, succeeded by another date, which is in turn succeeded by more data.  An example might make this more easily understood.

```
lis = {"a","b","January","1","2012","c","d","e","January","2","2012","f",
  "September","4","2012","w","y","z"}
```

I would like to have the dates transferred into `DateObject`s as follows:

```
res = {DateObject[{2012,1,1}],"c","d","e"}, 
   {DateObject[{2012,1,2}],"f"}, 
   {DateObject[{2012,9,4}],"w","y","z"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative:

```
months = Alternatives @@ {"January", "February", "March", "April", 
    "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
    "Novemeber", "December"};
days = Alternatives @@ Map[ToString, Range[31]];
years = Alternatives @@ Map[ToString, Range[3000]];
toDateObject[{m_, d_, y_}] := DateObject@DateString@StringRiffle[{m, d, y}, "/"]

SequenceSplit[
 list,
 {m : months, d : days, y : years, rest : Except[months] ..} :> {toDateObject[{m, d, y}], rest}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Possibly followed by `DeleteCases[sequences, {__String}]` to remove the first list without a date object in it.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** If dates are always in consecutive strings (month followed by day followed by year) in your list, a much faster alternative is possible using [`Split`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html):

```
ClearAll[reShape, f1 , f2]
monthnames = Alternatives @@ (DateString[#, "MonthName"] & /@ Thread[{2018, Range@12}]) ;
reShape [{a : monthnames, b_, c_, d___}] := {DateObject[DateString[{a,"/",b,"/",c}]], d}
reShape [_] := Nothing

f1 = reShape /@ Split[#, Not @ MatchQ[#2, monthnames]&]&; 

f1 @lis
```

[image]

For `lis` in OP, this is faster than

```
f2 = DeleteCases[SequenceSplit[#, {m : months,  d : days, y : years , 
       rest : Except[months] ..} :> {toDateObject[{m, d, y}], 
       rest} ], {__String}]  &; (* from C.E.'s answer *)

r1 = f1 @ lis;// RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0030

```
r2 = f2 @ lis ;// RepeatedTiming  // First
```

> 0.0046

```
r1 == r2
```

> True

For longer lists the difference is more significant:

```
lis2 = Join @@ RandomSample[ConstantArray[lis, 50]];
r1 = f1 @ lis2; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.152

```
r2 = f2 @ lis2; // RepeatedTiming  // First
```

> 4.52

```
r1 == r2
```

> True

Also, a small modification in `f2` doubles the speed:

```
ClearAll[f3]
f3 = DeleteCases[SequenceSplit[#, {m : months, d_, y_ , rest : Except[months] ..} :> 
  {toDateObject[{m, d, y}], rest} ], {__String}]  &;  

r3 = f3 @ lis2 ; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 2.11

```
r3 == r1
```

> True

**Original answer:**

Using [`SequenceSplit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceSplit.html)  and `` Internal`PossibleDateQ ``:

```
dQ = Internal`PossibleDateQ;
SequenceSplit[lis[[1 + LengthWhile[lis, Not @ dQ @ # &] ;;]], 
 {a_?dQ, b_, c_?dQ, d:Except[_?dQ] ..} :> {DateObject@DateString[{a, "/", b, "/", c}], d}]
```

> {{DateObject[{2012, 1, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], "c", "d", 
>     "e"}, {DateObject[{2012, 1, 2}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>     "f"}, {DateObject[{2012, 9, 4}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], "w", "y", 
>     "z"}}

Alternatively,

```
DeleteCases[SequenceSplit[lis, {a_?dQ, b_, c_?dQ,  d : Except[_?dQ] ..} :> 
  {DateObject @ DateString[{a, "/", b, "/", c}], d}], {__String}]
```

or

```
{DateObject @ DateString[Riffle[lis[[# ;; # + 2]], "/"]], 
  ## & @@ lis[[# + 3 ;; #2 - 1]] } & @@@ 
    Partition[Append[Flatten[Position[lis, _?dQ]][[;; ;; 2]], 1 + Length @ lis], 2, 1]
```

> same result

Comment: Yes, my data set has several thousand elements and the modifications suggested by kglr have helped speed things up greatly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
lis = {"a", "b", "January", "1", "2012", "c", "d", "e", "January", 
  "2", "2012", "f", "September", "4", "2012", "w", "y", "z"}

months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
   "July", "August", "September", "October", "Novemeber", "December"};

f[k_List, h_List] := Module[{temp = StringJoin @@ Riffle[k, " "]},
  {DateObject[temp], Sequence @@ h}
  ]

Split[lis, FreeQ[months, #2] &] // Select[Length@# > 2 &] // 
  Map[TakeDrop[#, 3] &] // Map[Apply[f]]
```

[image]